# Multiple insert lines after vertical bar

Tags: equations

I use:

```
$$\int\limits_a^b...dx\Bigg|_{^{a=...}_{b=...}}$$
```

and obtain:

[image]

I would like to raise the insert lines a little after vertical bar, if possible.

Comment: Without the \limits modifier the integration limits are located to the right of the integral symbol. Sorry for my off-topic: how did you make the gray background for "\limits"?

Comment: Just use backticks around `\limits`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$\int\limits_a^b...dx\Bigg|_{\raisebox{4pt}{$^{a=...}_{b=...}$}}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's what i needed, it's even the right letter size.

Comment: @misha.physics You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility with `stackengine`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{stackengine}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \int_a^b\! \dots\,dx\biggr\rvert_{\scriptstyle\stackMath \stackon{\scriptstyle a=\cdots}{\scriptstyle b=\cdots}}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about using smaller vertical bars? `\Bigg` seems needlessly, well, big.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\substack' and '\boxed' macros
\begin{document}
\[
\boxed{
\int_a^b\! \dots\,dx\Bigg\rvert_{\substack{a=\dots\\b=\dots}}
\qquad
\int_a^b\! \dots\,dx\bigg\rvert_{\substack{a=\dots\\b=\dots}}
\qquad
\int_a^b\! \dots\,dx\Big\rvert _{\substack{a=\dots\\b=\dots}}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked `\Bigg` size.

Comment: `\Bigg` seems needlessly without `\limits`. With him - just right as for me.